# How to create 3D-Plot in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

Please help me to create 3D-Plot in MatLab with this parameters:

```
x=t
y=t
z=2t^2
0<t<1
```

thank you!

Comment: [http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/2-and-3d-plots.html](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/2-and-3d-plots.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab plots data, not functions.  So, you need to generate data that represents your function.  Here I generate a vector containing 100 values of `t` from 0 to 1 (you could use linspace() for this if you prefer), then use it to generate the x, y, and z values:

```
t = [0 : 0.01 : 1]';
x = t;
y = t;
z = 2 * t.^2;

plot3(x,y,z, 'r-');
```

The plot3() call generates the plot as a red line connecting your x, y, z data points.